# How to same named argument into an array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I am new to Shell scripting. I've requriment to replace few string values in a file. They have to be read from command line and  shell script looks like below.

```
test.sh --old-value yahoo.com --new-value ibibo.io  --old-value xxxxxx --new-value yyy --exclude aa bb cc
```

Now, I want read --old-values into one array, --new-values into other array and --exclude into another array.

i am trying below approach.

```
  while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]
  do
    key="$1"

    case $key in



       --old-value)
       OLDVALUE="$2"
       shift # past argument
       ;;

       --new-value)
       NEWVALUE="$2"
       shift # past argument
       ;;

        --exclude)
        EXCLUDEFILETYPES=("$@")
       shift
        ;;

       *)
      # unknown option
    ;;
 esac
 shift # past argument or value
done
```

But this read the old value into OLDVALUE. I have to read both --old-values into an array.

Can someone help on how to  achieve this usecase?

Comment: Having two options is a bit verbose, especially since it would appear they *must* occur in pairs; any chance you can reduce it to a single option that takes two arguments? E.g., `test.sh --replace yahoo.com ibibo.io --replace xxxxx yyy --exclude aa bb cc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# declare arrays
old=(); new=(); exclude=()

while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; do
  key="$1"
  value="$2"
  [[ $key == --old-value ]] && old+=("$value")
  [[ $key == --new-value ]] && new+=("$value")
  [[ $key == --exclude   ]] && shift && exclude+=("$@")
  shift 2
done

# show content of arrays
declare -p old new exclude
```

I assume `--exclude aa bb cc` are last arguments.

---

Example: `./test.sh --old-value yahoo.com --new-value ibibo.io  --old-value xxxxxx --new-value yyy --exclude aa bb cc`

Output:

```
declare -a old='([0]="yahoo.com" [1]="xxxxxx")'
declare -a new='([0]="ibibo.io" [1]="yyy")'
declare -a exclude='([0]="aa" [1]="bb" [2]="cc")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
while (( $# )); do
    case "$1" in
    --old-value) old+=("$2") ;;
    --new-value) new+=("$2") ;;
    --exclude) shift; exc=("$@") ; break ;;
    --*) echo "bad arg" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    shift;shift
done
printf "old: %s\n" "${old[@]}"
printf "new: %s\n" "${new[@]}"
printf "exc: %s\n" "${exc[@]}"
```

output

```
old: yahoo.com
old: xxxxxx
new: ibibo.io
new: yyy
exc: aa
exc: bb
exc: cc
```

Of course, this still has problems. For example if the script is called as

```
--old-value yahoo.com --new-value --old-value xxxxxx --new-value yyy --exclude aa bb cc
```

note the missing new value argument. In such case the result will be of course wrong...

```
old: yahoo.com
new: --old-value
exc:
```

handling such error cases needs much more complicated state-handling.